# Full screen not working in youtube embedded player JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, flash, qt, youtube, pyqt

I am creating a PyQt Youtube player using the JavaScript player API. I used QWebView to load the url

```
http://www.youtube.com/e/VIDEO_ID?version=3&enablejsapi=1
```

The problem I face is that full screen button is not working for this. How do I overcome this?

Comment: For full screen you have to give small video width greater than 265 px